# How to write a persistence provider for Glassfish

Tags: java, jpa, glassfish, persistence, classloader

I have a special data storage ([Empire RDF](https://github.com/mhgrove/Empire)) I would like to use in my application with [CMT](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bncij.html) enabled.

For that, I imagine I have to write a [`PersistenceProvider`](http://glassfish.java.net/nonav/javaee5/api/javax/persistence/spi/PersistenceProvider.html), that I will then declare in a persistence.xml, with a jta-datasource and associated connection properties.

As a consequence, I tried to, but I always face deployment issues related to [PersistenceUnitLoader#loadPU](http://grepcode.com/file/maven.glassfish.org/content/repositories/glassfish-releases/org.glassfish.persistence/jpa-connector/3.0/org/glassfish/persistence/jpa/PersistenceUnitLoader.java#PersistenceUnitLoader.loadPU%28org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.PersistenceUnitDescriptor%29) (mainly the fact that it seems - to my ignorant eyes - that Glassfish confuses my PersistenceProvider with (Top/Eclipse)Link one).

So, what is the recommended way to create a PersistenceProvider for Glassfish for a non standard (read non related to a RDBMS) JPA implementation ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Writing a PersistenceProvider is in fact a quite stepforward task.

1. Create your persistence provider implementing the [`PersistenceProvider`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/spi/PersistenceProvider.html) interface. In my case, it was a subclass of Empire [`JPAPersistenceProvider`](https://github.com/mhgrove/Empire/blob/master/core/src/com/clarkparsia/empire/spi/JPAPersistenceProvider.java). Do not forget you can use properties read from `persistence.xml` using `persistenceUnitInfos.getProperties()`, but only in the [`PersistenceProvider#createContainerEntityManagerFactory`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/spi/PersistenceProvider.html#createContainerEntityManagerFactory%28javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceUnitInfo,%20java.util.Map%29) method !
2. In `persistence.xml`, write `<provider>mycompany.MyProvider</provider>`